# Set Transmission as default program when opening magnet links

Tags: chrome, bittorrent, transmission

How can I set up Chromium to open Transmission when clicking on a magnet link such as on TPB?

Chromium says that it will use xdg-open but that generally doesn't do anything

System: Manjaro Linux 0.8.5.2 fully upated

Desktop Environment: Xfce 4.10

Comment: Xfce hardly any settings have been changed from default

Answer (score 17):

Chromium obeys the system-wide xdg settings. To configure opening magnet links with a custom application use the following command

```
xdg-mime default transmission-gtk.desktop x-scheme-handler/magnet
```

You can also do this manually: Open the file `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` and add the following entry in the section `[Default Applications]`:

```
x-scheme-handler/magnet=transmission-gtk.desktop
```

You can confirm the new setting with

```
xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/magnet
```

Comment: I did that however I still get                'Unable to to detect URI-scheme of'

Comment: @abacusasian What does the last command from my answer return?

Comment: @Marco, I tried your steps and although I get `transmission-gtk.desktop` as output from the xdg-mime command, nothing happens when I click on a magnet link in chrome.

Comment: @Marco 'transmission-gtk.desktop'

Comment: @Marco I have the same problem abacusasian has, and your solution did not work :(

Comment: ran this method in Ubuntu 18.04 LXDE and works perfectly altho the Open xdg-open popup still appears but when I click on it it DOES open in Transmission now ...    so thank you
Thought of the addendum here as many might see the pop-up and think nothing has changed

Comment: + to get rid of xdg-open popup and just work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51986354/how-to-temove-open-xdg-open-dialogue-from-ubuntu-chrome-while-opening-specific-l

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with Debian Jessie, running the xfce desktop.  It seems to be a bug in exo-open, which pops up a window saying "Unable to to detect URI-scheme of..." when asked to open a magnet link.  Updating to the latest version of exo-utils solved the problem for me:

in debian:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install exo-utils
```