# Using Evince instead of Okular for Alpine (MIME configuration for PDF viewers)

Tags: pdf, mime-types, alpine-mail

Within Alpine, if I hit enter on a PDF attachment, my system brings up Okular. I  would prefer if it brought up Evince, because that's the PDF viewer I normally use. How can I do that? This is clearly a MIME issue, but I'm not sure how to (re)-configure things to make this work.

`/etc/mailcap` is probably relevant. it has bucketloads of stuff in it, and mentions both Okular and Evince in the context of PDF without obviously preferring one over the other.

UPDATE: Actually, [this answer to an earlier question of mine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/88794/) might do the trick as well. Need to check.

UPDATE 2: I ran

```
xdg-mime default evince.desktop application/pdf
```

and now I see an entry in `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`

```
application/pdf=evince.desktop
```

under both the sections "[Added Associations]" and "[Default Applications]",
but Alpine is still using Okular. (I also restarted Alpine.) What am I missing?

Comment: You can investigate by running Alpine under `strace`, which should tell you what configuration files it reads. It may invoke some other program to do the job; use `strace -f` to get a trace for subprocesses as well.

Comment: Alpine usually uses the default pdf viewer of the system. So if Evince is the default, it is a good idea to uninstall then reinstall Alpine. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like it's ignoring the per-user settings. You can change the systemwide setting by editing `/etc/mailcap.order`, the syntax is fairly simple:

```
first-choice-app-name:mime-type
second-choice-app-name:mime-type
...
```

So you'd probably put:

```
evince-previewer:application/pdf
evince:application/pdf
```

(evince-previewer is fairly new, may not exist in Wheezy, but having it there is harmless).

Then you run `/usr/sbin/update-mime` to update `/etc/mailcap`.

Answer (score 2):

Alpine reads per-user "mailcap" settings from `~/.mailcap`, which overrides the systemwide `/etc/mailcap`. So just put the following line in `~/.mailcap`:

```
application/pdf; evince %s
```

Comment: Works well and doesn't require super user clearance.